# I want to replace all occurrences of certain characters in my file with words

Tags: unix, vi

My file contains this type of data:

```
R>M#1290###H1148ZM/A##3#RA##</R>
```

I want to change value for single part number `H1148ZM/A` from `3` to `100` and the occurrences of partnumber in the file is more than 10 times. How to change this using UNIX vi?

Comment: Can you a dd a bit more context? Right now, it is not clearly understandable, what you want to replace. You want to replace the 3 with a 100 in every line where H1148ZM/A occurs?

Then try :%s/OLD/NEW/g with H1148ZM/A##3 as value for OLD and  H1148ZM/A##100 as value for NEW

Comment: yes...Exactly wants to change with 100 everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:%s/H1148ZM\/A##3/H1148ZM\/A##100/g
```

The slashes in the search term have to be escaped to distinguish them from the regular slashes used in the s/// expression.